# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'common')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const CountryDetail = () => {
    const {countryname}=useParams();
    const[countrydet,setCountry]=useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const url=`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${countryname}`;
        fetch(url)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>setCountry(data))
    },[])
    return (
        <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
            
            <h3>This is country details : {countryname}</h3>
            <h4>{countrydet.name.common}</h4>
            <h4>{countrydet.continents}</h4>
            
        </div>
    );
};
```

export default CountryDetail;

> but there is a element in object
> {"name":{"common":"Bangladesh","official":"People's Republic of Bangladesh","nativeName":{"ben":{"official":"বাংলাদেশ গণপ্রজাতন্ত্রী","common":"বাংলাদেশ"}}}

Answer (score 1):

When the component first renders, the asynchronous API call and setting of state hasn't happened yet, so `countrydet` is undefined.

```
            <h3>This is country details : {countryname}</h3>
            <h4>{countrydet?.name?.common}</h4>
            <h4>{countrydet?.continents}</h4>
```

This should work, and [here's the MDN reference for optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

or alternatively, you could wrap the whole block in a conditional, something like this:

```
            <h3>This is country details : {countryname}</h3>
            { countrydet?.name?.common && countrydet?.continent ? 
               <>
                 <h4>{countrydet?.name?.common}</h4>
                 <h4>{countrydet?.continents}</h4>
               </>
               :
               <></>
             }
```

Comment: There may be a slight formatting error in your answer--it uses double curly spaces when you likely intended to only use a single one.

Comment: @Jokinen Ah yes good spot! Thanks for catching - I've updated the answer to correct this. Clearly I've been using too much Angular recently and forgot single curly braces are a thing!

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, set an initial state for `countrydet` .
- Then correctly unwrap the response from the fetch request. `.then(([data]) => setCountry(data));`
- Check if the `countryname` parameter is set before executing the fetch request.
- Check if `countrydet` is defined before trying to access it's properties.

```html
const CountryDetail = () => {
  const { countryname } = useParams();
  const [countrydet, setCountry] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (countryname) {
      const url = `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${countryname}`;
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(([data]) => setCountry(data));
    }
  }, [countryname]);

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h3>This is country details : {countryname}</h3>
      {countrydet && (
        <>
          <h4>{countrydet.name.common}</h4>
          <h4>{countrydet.continents}</h4>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```